# Copy files with certain extension created within last half an hour with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy files (.zip) that has been created in the last half an hour and using the below script for that but for some reason all the zip files in the source directory get copied over. Can you please help me in correcting it?

```
copy-item C:\ABC\\*.zip -filter (Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}) -destination C:\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ABC\*.zip | Where { $_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination C:\ }
```

I am not sure why `filter` is not working, but this gets a list of all the zips, filters that down to the ones with the correct times, and then issues the copy statement.

Comment: `-Filter` in the OP's example is being passed and object array from the file system. Typically `-Filters` are composed of string arrays.

Comment: Thanks but it gives the following error: "Where-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'FilterScript'. Cannot convert the "CreationTime" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
"

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser this syntax is only good for newer powershell versions 3.0+ I think.  Try using {} for the clause. `Where {CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}`

Comment: @Matt, I didn't know that was new syntax. I've updated to use the scriptblock-style syntax.